# How do I represent large delays in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl, test-bench

I want to use a delay of 5s in my Verilog testbench. However, the time scaling is `1ns/1ps`. I do not want to change this scaling since it effects my clock.

But, how can I write a delay of 5s which is easy to read? Like `#5e9`?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use a real literal

```
#5.0e9
```

Better would be to use SystemVerilog and write

```
#5s
```

Answer (score 2):

`#5e9` works on all simulators on [EDA playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/Kni9):

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module tb;

initial begin
    #5e9;
    $display("Time=%0t", $time);
end

endmodule
```